# (VB) Timer carries on other forms

Tags: vb.net, timer

Basically, when I continue onto the next form my timer is still running, how can I stop this?
I have already used "Timer1.Enabled = False"

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            MsgBox("Sorry, your time has expired. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Warning")
            Me.Close()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you set the Timer1.Enabled to false?

Comment: Timer1.Enabled = False .. before Me.close

Comment: Let me correct myself, the forms after don't close after the timer is up (which is what is supposed to happened anyway), but the message box still pops up and @matzone that hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you handling the form_Closing event and canceling it?

Comment: By far the simplest solution is to drop a timer on the form with the designer.  Which ensures that the timer is automatically disposed when the form is closed.  If you create one yourself in code then you'll have to call its Dispose() method in an event handler for the FormClosed event.

Comment: @HansPassant This timer was dropped onto the form designer.

Comment: There are various ways to shoot your foot in VB.NET, accidentally creating extra instances of a form class that are not visible.  Which happens when you use the class name of the form instead of the object reference.  The code snippet is too incomplete to finger this reason.  Note how the answer you accepted doesn't solve the problem, the timer still keeps ticking if the user closed the form instead of your code.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the real problem is the MessageBox that engulfs the message queue. If the Timer was disposed immediately the ticks in the message queue are still there and will trigger the event. Am I wrong?

Comment: "Ticks" are not stored in the message queue.  The Tick event handler can however certainly run again while the message box is displayed and the timer wasn't stopped first.  Easy to see, you get another message box.  Nothing otherwise goes wrong, calling Close() twice doesn't cause trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using a Windows timer.

If this is true then your first message box has the unwanted side effect to accumulate a number of Tick events in the message queue of your program.

More time you stay in video with your message box displayed more message boxes will be displayed because the messages  accumulate in the queue

You could try to solve this situation with a global form variable

```
Dim timeElapsed as Boolean 

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   if timeElapsed = False then
        timeElapsed = true ' It is important that you set immediatly this to true
        MsgBox("Sorry, your time has expired. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Warning")
        Me.Close()
        Dim t = CType(sender, Timer)
        t.Elapsed = false
   End If
End Sub
```

Also check about the Hans Passant advice about the Disposing of the Timer

Comment: Thank you, er what is "Timer(t" and "t.Elapsed"?

Comment: Sorry, mixup with C# declarations. However, I am trying to convert the sender object to the corrisponding Timer sender and then using this to stop the calling timer. You could access the Timer1 directly though.

Comment: How do I go by doing this?